# 301 Redirect with Partial Filename Change

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

Here are some examples of the old URLs:

```
http://www.test.com/files/Old_Name.zip 
http://www.test.com/files/Old_Name.php 
http://www.test.com/files/Old_Name_Setup.php 
http://www.test.com/files/Old_Name_100_Setup.php
```

Here are what the new URLs look like:

```
http://www.test.com/files/New_Name.zip 
http://www.test.com/files/New_Name.php 
http://www.test.com/files/New_Name_Setup.php 
http://www.test.com/files/New_Name_100_Setup.php
```

I need to edit my .htaccess file to reflect these changes, so when people visit the old URLs, they are taken to the new URLs.

I've seen something like

```
Redirect 301 /files/Old_Name.php http://www.test.com/files/New_Name.php
```

Unfortunately, this way would require me to do this for every single file, and there are a lot. I'm guessing I'm going to have to use `regex`, but I haven't seen a solution online that only modifies part of the filename. I'm assuming this should be able to be done in 1 line as the structure change between old and new URLs is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in `/files/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Old_Name(.*)$ New_Name$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Or in root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^files/Old_Name(.*)$ files/New_Name$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```